# Advice Please - Basic For Loop Efficiency in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-loops, enumerate, coding-efficiency

First off, I want to clarify that I am currently learning Python. So this will probably be a beginner level question. Thanks in advance for any advice/responses.

Currently, the course I'm taking is going into loops and iterations. I decided to do some work on my own and come up with my own challenges for simple practice.

My personal challenge:
**Create and store a string in a variable, then using enumerator, output the string in reverse order.**

***I am aware that there are other ways to accomplish this, however, I'm purposefully trying to learn how much flexibility enumerator can offer.*

I went through several formats that I knew where the most efficient, however, the best one I could come up with (based on my current knowledge) was this:

```
mystring1 = 'Zero'

for index,letter in enumerate(mystring1):
    if index == 0:
        index0 = index,letter
        print('First Index:',index0,'\n')
        index += 1
        if index == 1:
            index1 = index,letter
            print('Second Index:',index1,'\n')
            index += 1
            if index == 2:
                index2 = index,letter
                print('Third Index:',index2,'\n')
                index += 1
                if index == 3:
                    index3 = index,letter
                    print('Fourt Index:',index3,'\n')
                    index += 1
                else:
                    
                    continue
            else:
                
                continue
        else:
            
            continue
    else:
        print('All Letters Captured')
        break
    
    print(index3, index2, index1, index0)
```

With the above code, this is my output, however, two problems: I'm not grabbing the letter to the corresponding index and I don't feel I accomplished it the most efficiently.

```
First Index: (0, 'Z') 

Second Index: (1, 'Z') 

Third Index: (2, 'Z') 

Fourt Index: (3, 'Z') 

(3, 'Z') (2, 'Z') (1, 'Z') (0, 'Z')
All Letters Captured
```

I have a bit of knowledge in C#, and my main fear was to get a an output similar to an array; where I would have all possible combinations.

Any tips or pieces of advice would be awesome. Just trying to learn!

Thanks again for everyone's time!

Comment: (Assuming you can't use the built-in [`reversed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) function.)  Have you learned about [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list)s yet?

Comment: We have been over lists, and the reversed function, however, I was attempting to do this using enumerator. Unless that is something I can incorporate with enumerator? This may not be possible the way I'm trying to do this. To correct for the Z being pulled everytime, I can only think of nesting more functions.

Comment: How would you write it in c#? Do you need to do `if index == N`? Looking at the code, I see a clear pattern which doesnt need repeating `print('Nth Index:',index0,'\n')`

Comment: Well, I'm not sure how enumerate would translate to C# as my knowledge is limited as well. However, the syntax for for loops in C# make it a little easier for me visualize. But it wouldn't grab an index. I just know that I would be wary of grabbing "all possible outcomes"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the first problem is that your code is not doing what you want it to do, not that it isn't efficient. Because you have `index += 1` at the end of each if statement, the program actually assigns all indexes in the first loop (thats why the letter associated with each index is `Z`. A cleaner approach that works might look like

```
a = []                                                                                                                
for index,letter in enumerate(mystring1):                                                                                 
    a.insert(0,(index,letter))
```

`a` is a list, and each time we call `a.insert(0,...)` we prepend that list (effectively reversing the enumerator). It outputs

```
[(3, 'o'), (2, 'r'), (1, 'e'), (0, 'Z')]
```

Comment: I see what you're saying. Are you running a just print after your for expression? The output I'm getting is 4 lines. Starting with 0,Z and gaining one (backwards) each lines. If so, is there a way to just output that last line?

Comment: I'm not entirely understanding. The `[(3, 'o'), (2, 'r'), (1, 'e'), (0, 'Z')] ` comes from `print(a)`. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Sorry, I can see how what I type wasn't the best way to ask that question. However, yes that does answer my question. Thank you!